# DWM memory leak on NVIDIA GPU while running simple UWP app

Tags: memory-leaks, uwp, nvidia, composition, dwm

I have 2 GPUs in my laptop: Intel HD Graphics 4600 and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M

While running simple UWP app using Windows.UI.Composition API I've noticed that my desktop freezes. Checked my processes and found out that DWM consumes a lot of memory.

[image]

While running through amount of forums someone said just to turn off NVIDIA and retry with integrated GPU. Though the answer was about DWM memory leak while playing some game it solved the issue.

[image]

Difference is amazing. But I haven't found the main answer - WHY?!

I also tried this trick with NVIDIA GTX 760 and 980 - the same result.

Using NVIDIA is primary objective for my app.

Comment: trace the memory allocations with WPR.exe/WPA.exe: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-154-Memory-Footprint-and-Leaks#time=16m57s, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/memory-footprint-optimization-exercise-2 and look with functions allocate so much memory

Answer (score 1):

I found where is the problem.

In my app I used PNG circle image as mask brush, after changing it to XAML Ellipse with method GetAlphaMask() the problem disappeared. Conclusion - DO NOT USE IMAGES AS MASK TO YOUR BRUSHES FOR SPRITEVISUALS ON NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: you should report this to nVIDIA in their forums: https://forums.geforce.com/default/board/33/geforce-drivers/